# Maven store MD5 checksum of file and file size in properties then filter another file

Tags: maven, properties, maven-plugin, advanced-installer

I am wondering if there is a way in Maven to calculate the MD5 checksum and size of a file, put them into properties then use those properties to filter (text replace) parameters in another file. I am trying to generate a config file for Advanced Installer before I run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a while googling for ways to do it with Maven I decided to look into using the antrun plugin. I googled for both features and the first link of both solved the problem. Seems like antrun is a great way to script most things in Maven.

My antrun configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <property name="my_path" value="some path"/>
                    <length file="${my_path}" property="file.size"/>
                    <checksum file="${my_path}" property="file.md5"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maven resources plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>file1</include>
                    <include>file2</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Which works great from the command line but for some reason the properties are not resolved in Intellij. [I've posted another question for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343570/maven-build-is-not-filtering-properties-in-intellij)